# IRepository in project which my Repository project references makes it hard to actually use them

Tags: entity-framework, repository, automapper

I'm currently working in asp.net mvc 4 with EF5 and I'm trying to get my Dependency Injection to work with Ninject.

I've made 4 different projects in my solution:

- Gui -> contains my MVC-project
- BusinessLogic -> BusinessLogic
- DataAccess -> my edmx-file and Repository (references Common)
- Common -> Models, ViewModels and IRepository.

Now I'm trying to write this:

IRepository:

```
    IQueryable<PictureSource> PictureSource { get; }
```

Repository:

```
    IQueryable<PictureSource> IRepository.PictureSource
        {
            get { return context.PictureSource }
        }
```

Now the problem is I can't call on PictureSource in my IRepository because it's an Entity from my EF, which is in my DataAccess. I've tried using automapper the following way in my Repository:

```
     public IQueryable<PictureSourceModel> PictureSource()
        {
            Mapper.CreateMap<List<PictureSource>, List<PictureSourceModel>>();
     return Mapper.Map<List<PictureSource>,List<PictureSourceModel>>
     (context.PictureSource.ToList());
        }
```

This gives errors about it beind a dbSet.
Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't access some Model classes from your IRepository then you didn't apply your structure.

The `PictureSourceModel` class **and all other Entities should be in your Common Project.**
Then "as expected" all other projects will get access to these classes.

To be able to separate EF Entities to another Project you may consider to use Visual Studio Extension called "***Ef DbContext Generator***".

If you want more help tell me.

*BTW: Try not to use AutoMapper in DAL. It should used in Gui project.*

---

***Update***

To separate Entities to POCO classes

- Install Visual Studio Extension called "***Ef DbContext
  Generator***".
- Open your edmx file and right click in empty area then chose "Add
  Code Generation Item"
- From the list select "Ef DbContext Generator"
- Then just move the new file to another project
- After that you should open .tt file to correct the .edmx file path

Comment: PictureSource is the Entity that EF generated. I can get it by using context.PictureSource. The problem is that I can't call it in my Common layer as I already have to reference that layer in my DataAccess-layer. My Repository (which contains my context and context.pictureSource) is still in my DataAccess. I can't call DataAccess from Common due to circular reference.

Comment: As i told you. You could separate Entity classes to another Project by using DbContext Generator toll. Look to my update

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I've been very busy. This has worked for me and I thank you for your help.